# Is that necessary to register scripts with @Html.Requires() if I am using @Styles.Render()?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I is a asp net mvc 4 application and I am integrating an asp net mvc 3 app in it.
I have imported all js and css scripts and reference it using bundles.

Thing is this asp net mvc 3 application has a couples of @Html.Requires() (one for each js and css file.).

As I have never developed using asp net mvc 3, I am not sure those @Html.Requires() are nescessary. Also the documentation I found in microsoft msdn did not help much.

Comment: Mate, I have already found out that all the problem was with Ajax request. My views are loaded through ajax call, and the plugin I was using does not work with Ajax. I have it removed from my project. I ´am buzy now but I will download the plugin again and at night I post here to you. There is @Html.Requires and thanks for your attention ;O) Talk to you later.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605109/what-is-the-purpose-of-library-registration-and-does-it-make-any-difference-if-i/14609843#14609843  Here you can find what I was talking about. Check the awnser.